# Why do I get zombie puppeteer processes on alpine/docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, alpine-linux

Here is the entirety of my puppeteer controller:

```
import { Readability } from '@mozilla/readability';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const summarize = require('summarize');
const keyword_extractor = require('keyword-extractor');
const amex = require('../../csv/AMEX.json');
const nasdaq = require('../../csv/NASDAQ.json');
const nyse = require('../../csv/NYSE.json');
const cryptotickers = require('../../csv/cryptos.json');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

class Reader {
  constructor() {
    this.browser = null;
  }

  async getLink(link) {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      devtools: false,
      headless: true,
      // product: 'firefox',
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: [
        '--proxy-server=' + process.env.PROXY_HOST,
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--single-process',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--shm-size=4gb',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
        '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
        // '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"'
      ],
    });

    const { htm, title } = await this.spa(link);

    if (!htm) {
      await this.browser.close();
      return;
    }

    const text = txt(htm, link);
    const data = Object.assign({}, text);
    const parts = new URL(link);

    if (!data.title) {
      data.title = title;
    }

    data.summary = summary(data.content, data.title);
    data.tickers = tickers(data.content, data.textContent);
    data.cryptos = cryptos(data.content, data.textContent);
    data.meta = getMeta(htm);

    if (!data.title && data.meta.title) {
      data.title = data.meta.title;
    }

    data.url = link;
    data.htm = htm;
    data.host = parts.host;
    data.text = data.textContent;
    delete data.textContent;

    console.log('data fetched: ' + link);
    await this.browser.close();
    // await this.browser.disconnect();

    return data;
  }

  async spa(url) {
    let htm;
    let title;

    try {
      let page = await this.browser.newPage();

      await page.setRequestInterception(true);
      page.on('request', (req) => {
        if (
          req.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' ||
          req.resourceType() === 'font' ||
          req.resourceType() == 'image'
        ) {
          req.abort();
        } else {
          req.continue();
        }
      });

      await page.authenticate({
        username: process.env.PROXY_USER,
        password: process.env.PROXY_PASS,
      });

      await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
      // await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
      await this.autoScroll(page);
      await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, 50));
      htm = await page.content();
      title = await page.evaluate(() => document.title);

      if (htm.indexOf('<title') === -1) {
        htm = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
      }

      console.log(title, 'title');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err, url);
    }

    return { htm, title };
  }

  async autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const maxScroll = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
          let lastScroll = 0;
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
            window.scrollBy(0, document.body.offsetHeight);
            const { scrollTop } = document.documentElement;
            if (scrollTop === maxScroll || scrollTop === lastScroll) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              resolve();
            } else {
              lastScroll = scrollTop;
            }
          }, 1000);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error); // add catch here
      });
    });

    // await page.evaluate(async () => {
    //     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //         let totalHeight = 0;
    //         let distance = 300;
    //         let timer = setInterval(() => {
    //             const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    //             window.scrollBy(0, distance);
    //             totalHeight += distance;

    //             if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
    //                 clearInterval(timer);
    //                 resolve();
    //             }
    //         }, 100);
    //     });
    // });
  }
} // end Class Reader

async function summarization2(text) {
  let res;
  let data;

  console.log(text, process.env.DEEPAI_KEY);

  try {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('text', text);

    res = await fetch(`https://api.deepai.org/api/summarization`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
      headers: {
        'api-key': process.env.DEEPAI_KEY,
      },
    });

    data = await res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  return data;
}
async function sentiment(text) {
  return await deepai.callStandardApi('sentiment-analysis', { text });
}

async function summarization(text) {
  return await deepai.callStandardApi('summarization', { text }).catch(console.error);
}

function summary(text, title) {
  if (!text) return {};
  const summary = summarize(`${title} - ${text}`);

  summary.topics = keyword_extractor
    .extract(`${title} - ${text}`, {
      language: 'english',
      remove_digits: true,
      return_changed_case: true,
      remove_duplicates: false,
    })
    .map(process);

  const counts = summary.topics.reduce(
    (acc, value) => ({
      ...acc,
      [value]: (acc[value] || 0) + 1,
    }),
    {},
  );

  let topics = [];

  for (let topic in counts) {
    topics.push({ topic, count: counts[topic] });
  }

  topics = topics.filter((t) => t.topic);
  topics = topics.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.count - a.count;
  });

  topics = topics.slice(0, 10);
  topics = topics.map((topic) => topic.topic);
  summary.topics = topics;

  function process(topic) {
    topic = topic.toLowerCase().trim();
    topic = topic.replace(/[\W_]+/g, '');
    topic = topic.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

    return topic;
  }

  console.log('summary: ', summary);

  return summary;
}

function tickers(htm, text) {
  if (!text) return {};

  const tickers = [];

  function findTicker(ticker, exchange) {
    let name = ticker.Name;

    if (name && name.indexOf('Twitter') === -1 && name.indexOf('Facebook') === -1) {
      name = name.replace(/,? ?Inc\.?/gi, '').replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${name}\\b`, 'gi');

    if (text.match(regex)) {
      console.log(name);
      console.log(regex.toString());
      tickers.push({ name: ticker.Name, symbol: ticker.Symbol, exchange });
    }
  }

  amex.forEach((ticker) => {
    findTicker(ticker, 'amex');
  });
  nasdaq.forEach((ticker) => {
    findTicker(ticker, 'nasdaq');
  });
  nyse.forEach((ticker) => {
    findTicker(ticker, 'nyse');
  });

  console.log(tickers);

  return tickers;
}

function cryptos(htm, text) {
  if (!text) return {};

  const tickers = [];

  function findTicker(ticker) {
    const name = ticker.name.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${name}\\b`, 'g');

    if (text.match(regex)) {
      console.log(name);
      console.log(regex.toString());
      tickers.push({ name: ticker.name, symbol: ticker.symbol });
    }
  }

  cryptotickers.forEach(findTicker);

  console.log(tickers);

  return tickers;
}

function getMeta(htm) {
  const doc = new JSDOM(htm);
  const meta = {};
  const thumb =
    doc.window.document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]') ||
    doc.window.document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]');
  const title = doc.window.document.title;

  meta.title = title;
  meta.thumb = thumb && thumb.getAttribute('content');

  return meta;
}

function txt(htm, link) {
  const url = new URL(link);
  const doc = new JSDOM(htm);
  doc.window.document
    .querySelectorAll('img')
    .forEach(
      (el) =>
        (el.src =
          el.src.indexOf('http') === 0 || el.src.indexOf('//') === 0
            ? el.src.indexOf('http://')
              ? el.src.replace('http:', '')
              : el.str
            : '//' + url.host + el.src),
    );
  doc.window.document
    .querySelectorAll('a[href]')
    .forEach(
      (el) =>
        (el.href =
          el.href && el.href.indexOf('/') === 0
            ? url.protocol + '//' + url.host + el.href
            : el.href),
    );
  const reader = new Readability(doc.window.document);
  return reader.parse();
}

export default Reader;
```

For some reason after a few days the docker container has too many puppeteer processes because for some reason when fetching urls the browser doesn't exit properly.

Eventually the container is out of resources and the entire app freezes and is inaccessible.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running puppeteer in docker and getting a pile of zombie processes too.

Comment: no, i did not find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when using Puppeteer inside docker. The solution was to implement [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) within docker. The `Dockerfile` should somehow look like this then (I assume you are developing a node-project therefore we call `npm start` at the end:

```
RUN apt-get install dumb-init // ... plus your other packages
... your remaining docker things
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: can you explain what this actually does? i haven't heard of it.

Comment: also what is the entry point second argument?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#what-dumb-init-does) it just handles signals handler better than the usual init-system.
The second `--` parameter, acts like a "proxy-shell" inside your docker. Explained [here](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#what-dumb-init-does).
Hope this could help

Comment: Didn't fix my problem. Still getting stale puppeteer processes that won't close.

Comment: @chovy were you able to fix it? I have tried dumb-init but Puppeteer hangs on the second attempt.

Comment: no. i never did figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of zombie processes from using Puppeteer within a Docker environment as well; seems to have been solved by having the following at the top of the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    init: true
```

Others have linked to the documentation, but I didn't find a clear example of "how" that applied to my scenario.